# Displaying the nested json with images in an table using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to render nested JSON with has images in it in HTML table using vanilla javascript, I tried my things but not able to get this in HTML table. here is the link for my code [Codepen](https://codepen.io/manoj1991/pen/qgQrYm)

Expected output:
[image]

HTML Code:

```
    <table id="product">
        <th>Products</th>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

JS Code:

```
var product_catalog = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/prate3k/f03c7d20e235e2cd81b1bf608858da55/raw/8b6bcf994e4112d4261644eb7dca29fec532e4e1/sample-product-response.json";

    var output = document.querySelector("#product tbody");

    function build(JSONObject) {
        /**get all keys***/
        var keys = Object.keys(JSONObject);
        /**get all subkeys***/

        var subkeys = Object.keys(JSONObject[keys]);
        console.log(subkeys);
        /**loop sub keys to build HTML***/
        for (var i = 0, tr, td; i < subkeys.length; i++) {
            tr = document.createElement("tr");
            td = document.createElement("td");
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(subkeys[i]));
            tr.appendChild(td);
            output.appendChild(tr);
        }
    }

    build(product_catalog);
```

Comment: what is your expected output, images are included in the compare object. you only need to show images. can you show what is your expected output

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting keys from an object but from a JSON string. Use JSON.parse before fetching its keys.

```
function build(JSONObject) {

        JSONObject = JSON.parse(JSONObject);
        /**get all keys***/
        var keys = Object.keys(JSONObject);
        /**get all subkeys***/

        var subkeys = Object.keys(JSONObject[keys]);
        console.log(subkeys);
        /**loop sub keys to build HTML***/
        for (var i = 0, tr, td; i < subkeys.length; i++) {
            tr = document.createElement("tr");
            td = document.createElement("td");
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(subkeys[i]));
            tr.appendChild(td);
            output.appendChild(tr);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.